# I receive NULL values when trying to send Ajax jQuery parameters in POST request - MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to send `subscriberemail` parameter to action result in the controller but i receiving null value when trying to send ajax jquery parameters in post.

```js
    $("#button-subscribe-newsletter").click(function () {
        debugger
        if ($('#subscribe_form_email').val().length > 0)
        {
            if (isEmail($('#subscribe_form_email').val())) {

                var obj = {};
                obj["subscriberemail"] = $("#subscribe-form-email").val();

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '/CreateSubscribe/Create',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: obj,
                    success: function (d) {
                        if (d.val == true) {
                            $("#subscribenewsletterform").hide();
                            $("#Success-Message").show();
                            $("#Failed-Message").hide();
                            $("#Null-Message").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#Failed-Message").show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#Null-Message").show();
            }
              
        } else {
            $("#Null-Message").show();
        }

        });
```

```html
   <input type="email" id="subscribe_form_email" name="subscribe-form-email" class="bg-transparent text-small no-margin border-color-medium-dark-gray" placeholder="<%= LocalizationHelpers.Resource(null,"Enteryouremail", "ContentResources") %>">
                                    <button id="button-subscribe-newsletter"  type="submit" class="btn btn-arrow-small position-absolute border-color-medium-dark-gray">
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-right no-margin-left"></i></button>
```

and this is the controller

```
 public class CreateSubscribeController : Controller
{
    // GET: CreateSubscribe
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Create(string subscriberemail)
    {

        var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "Email",subscriberemail }
        };

        if (SitefinityWebApp.Helpers.SitefinityHelper.CreateSubscriberAndAddToMailingList(MailList.Maillist, subscriberemail))
        {
            SitefinityWebApp.Helpers.SitefinityHelper.SendEmailByTemplate(EmailTemplates.SubscribeEmail, subscriberemail, keys);
            return Json(new { val = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { val = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice

Comment: Typo.  The id has underscores.  The selector has dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below in your Jquery

```
obj["subscriberemail"] = $("#subscribe_form_email").val();
```

Comment: instead you can send variable directly as data: subscriberemail in your ajax.

Comment: Given that the issue is just a typo in the selector, this is applicable to be closed due to a typo, not answered.